# Windows not detected while installing Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, 17.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my laptop but it is not detecting windows,when I install that on somewhere else and restart then it is not showing Ubuntu so now how should I install Ubuntu along side with windows 10?

Comment: You need to supply more details, @Rakshith B H! Did you install Ubuntu (version ?) on the same HDD as Windows-10? How did you prepare bootable USB stick for Ubuntu? What does the phrase `when I install somewhere else` mean? What is the brand of your laptop? Do you have any SSDs? While installing Ubuntu, did you observe such as `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb`, etc. while partitioning? Did you see bootloaders in BIOS setup screen after installation? What are they?

Comment: Install along side with windows option is not showing I'm using dell laptop and it does not have ssd, I have created partition on hard-disk

Comment: There are two items play important role in ubuntu installation: 1.  Preparation of Bootable USB stick for Ubuntu and 2. Set up priority for USB stick over windows-10 bootloader in BIOS setup screen. This will lead you Ubuntu installation screen where should select `/dev/sdb` (assume `/dev/sda` has windows-10 installation) to install Ubuntu. You may further partition `/dev/sdb` into `efi`,  `/`, `swap`, `home`, and so on as per your plan. After that, it is a cakewalk! Please tell  exactly where are you stuck? How did you prepare bootable USB stick for ubuntu? Please explain.